# Why I lost messages when using kafka with EOS Beta

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka 2.5.5.RELEASE and I lost message while using kafka with ExactlyOnceSemantic.

**Configuration**

My listener is using `@KafkaListener` with this containerConfiguration :

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory(
                ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
                AfterRollbackProcessor<Object, Object> afterRollbackProcessor,
                KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> kafkaTransactionManager,
                ConsumerRecordRecoverer myRecoverer
        ) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(afterRollbackProcessor);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setEosMode(ContainerProperties.EOSMode.BETA);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setBatchToRecordAdapter(new DefaultBatchToRecordAdapter<>(myRecoverer));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
    return factory;
}
```

```
@Bean
public AfterRollbackProcessor<?, ?> afterRollbackProcessor(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer) {
    return new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>(deadLetterPublishingRecoverer);
}
```

Properties :

```
spring.kafka.producer.acks = all
spring.kafka.consumer.isolation-level = read_committed
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = ap_u2
# Use hostname to generate unique transaction id per instance
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix = tx_ap_u2_${HOSTNAME}_
```

The topic has 3 partitions and I have 3 instances of my application, each instance consuming 1 partition.

**Problem**

I lost some messages in a read-process-write case.
The output topic did not receive the processed messages.

The DLT was empty and the listener continued processing the messages.

Messages lost were associated to error logs :

```
Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:23.696
org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory
commitTransaction failed: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@2a8419e]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.

Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:23.788
org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory
Error during some operation; producer removed from cache: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@2a8419e]

Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:23.979
org.springframework.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener
Exception thrown when sending a message with key='XXX' and payload='XXX' to topic XXX:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.

Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:23.981
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender
[Producer clientId=producer-XXXXXX.0, transactionalId=XXXXXX.0] Aborting producer batches due to fatal error
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.

26 times on different messages:
Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:23.985 to Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:24.787
org.springframework.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener
Exception thrown when sending a message with key='XXX' and payload='XXX' to topic XXX:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.

3 times this log :
Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:24.893
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient
[Producer clientId=producer-XXXXXX.0, transactionalId=XXXXXX.0] Uncaught error in request completion:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Should not reopen a batch which is already aborted.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.reopenAndRewriteProducerState(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:295)

6 times:
Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:24.890 to Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:24.887
org.springframework.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener
Exception thrown when sending a message with key='XXX' and payload='XXX' to topic XXX:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.

Nov 2, 2020 @ 16:04:25.085
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerCons
Producer or 'group.instance.id' fenced during transaction
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.
```

**Question**

Why 244 messages were lost using a read-process-write transactional listener with EOS.Beta semantic ?
Without any further information than the transaction was fenced.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known bug in kafka : [KAFKA-9803](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9803)

Workaround implemented in spring-kafka 2.5.8.RELEASE and 2.6.3.RELEASE

See stopContainerWhenFenced option

Answer (score 0):

> Producer or 'group.instance.id' fenced during transaction

With a `ProducerFencedException`, the rollback processor is not called because it means the consumer has lost those partitions. You should see rebalancing activity after that error. Since the offsets were not sent to the transaction, the same records should be redelivered, either to this instance or another one.

If you don't see a rebalance after that error, then something really strange happened.

**EDIT**

I just wrote a small test app and it works exactly as expected - when 2 copies are run; I get the same errors as you and it keeps failing on the same record.

```java
public class So64665725Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64665725Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so64665725", topics = "so64665725-1")
    public void listen(String in) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(in);
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        try {
            System.out.println(this.template.send("so64665725-2", in.toUpperCase()).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .getRecordMetadata());
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.getCause().printStackTrace();
            throw (Exception) e.getCause();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so64665725-1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so64665725-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=10000
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

spring.kafka.producer.acks=all
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=tx-
```

This is using Boot 2.4.0-RC1 and SK 2.6.2, which has EOSMode.BETA by default.

Comment: I don't see any other logs (i'm in WARN/ERROR level). The application is still running with prometheus metrics available but I don't know if there is any metrics for this

Comment: Are you generating the same errors ?
I still don't get why my messages are lost without any further information except that the transaction was expired and the messages are skipped and not rolledback

Comment: Yes; I get the exact same errors as you, with no record loss.

Comment: Any clue about the origin ? :s It seems like the batch failed, the afterRollback wasn't called, thus offset was not commit. But the listener continued on the next batch and committed the next batch such leading in the loss of the uncommitted batch ?

Comment: As I said; something strange must have happened; we can't re-seek the partitions (in the DARP) after a `ProducerFencedException`; we no longer have those partitions. If you can reliably reproduce this scenario with a small, complete, example; I can take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure ProducerFencedException means we lost partitions ?
In ```invokeBatchListenerInTx``` it just seems like the exception is logged and nothing else. So assuming the partitions are not lost and its just a temporary exception, the consume will resume and thus leading to my case. Is that possible ?

Comment: It shouldn't be that way. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-447%3A+Producer+scalability+for+exactly+once+semantics

Comment: It looks like the problem is your unusually small `transaction.timeout.ms`; I no longer see lost records when I increase it to 10 seconds. It does, however, mean we need to somehow detect that the fencing is due to a timeout Vs. fencing due to a rebalance - not sure right now how we can do that. In the meantime, you need to make sure the timeout is greater than the time it will take you to process a batch of records.

Comment: It's a known problem in the kafka-clients - see [KAFKA-9803](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9803).